# training error - what's the point?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, train

What's the overall point of training error in the goal of regression (i.e, making predictions)?

You might say something like, "well, you see, training error can help you determine which model of complexity is the best to use. "

And to that, some would say, "No you can't. Low training error could just mean that your model is conforming to whatever data you're training the model with, A.K.A overfitting"

What's the point of calculating training error if it's not a good predictive measure of performance?

Especially when we go through and say, to hell with training error, just use validation error..

When will we ever use training error?

Low training error can be indicative of overfitting.. is that the only use of it?

Comment: It's not clear what's the purpose of this question. "Low" training error is always relative. It's lower than test error, which leads you to conclude your model might be overfitting. You won't know train error is low until you calculate it.

Comment: That's pretty much my only point: What is training error good for other than helping to determine overfitting?

Answer (score 1):

Training error is used in estimating model parameters. Think about linear regression: if our model is $Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$ we estimate $\beta$ by minimizing $\vert \vert Y - Xv\vert \vert_2^2$ over $v \in \mathbb R^p$. This is just minimizing the training loss. Why does this make sense here? It's because we are considering models (i.e. different values of $v$) that all have the same complexity, so we just pick the one with the smallest loss (or in this case largest likelihood if we're assuming normal errors).

Once we're comparing models with different complexities we need to consider out-of-sample performance. Suppose in linear regression we are debating adding a quadratic term $\beta_2 x^2$ to the model $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x$. The model $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x$ is a special case of $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \beta_2 x^2$, which has greater complexity, so it is no longer fair to compare the losses.

If you're familiar with AIC and BIC, when two models have the same complexity we are just comparing likelihoods (i.e. losses), but when the dimensions of the models (i.e. complexities) differ, we then need to also take this into account.

Now let's think about machine learning methods like SVM: once we've fixed our tuning parameters, we are considering a bunch of models with the same flexibility so we can just choose the one that fits the data best. It is only when we are comparing models with different complexities (i.e. when we tune the cost and kernel parameters, and maybe choose the kernel) that we need to consider out of sample performance.

As far as how to "use" it, I don't really pay attention to the training error per se, but it can appear in certain calculations that I do pay attention to. For example, in linear regression the sum of the squared residuals, a value that is quite useful, is just the total training loss if we're using squared loss.

Comment: however, training error doesn't have to be defined to be the exact same as the loss function. For example, training error can be defined as the average of the residuals (rss/n), even though you're using rss in your gradient descent algorithm (hill climbing) to find the minimum.. (or you could use ridge regression which is has a loss function defined as RSS + lambda*L2_norm, but still use training error as the average rss, etc) (need to split this up into two comments)

Comment: (continued) but what I basically think you're getting at is that training error is pretty much useless if we aren't trying to look at overfitting or unless complexity stays the same between models and we are only trying to figure out the particular parameters of the model. Is that correct?

Comment: (that is, unless complexity stays the same between models AND you've defined training error to be your loss function, instead of something different, like the average of the loss function.. otherwise you're not using training error to determine model parameters.. you're using the loss function)

Comment: Loss is separate from regularization. In ridge regression it's still squared loss but we add a quadratic penalty. The loss function has not changed though. Either way, my main point is just that training error is very important for choosing model parameters but it's not so useful to the human practitioner, since we don't choose the model parameters, only the hyperparameters.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that the loss function is different from the cost function in gradient descent. For example, it sounds like you are saying, when you are using rss + lamda*L2_norm as the cost function in gradient decent, the loss function is still only rss. Is that correct? Also...

Comment: (continued) Also, how are you defining training error? It sounds like you are defining training error to be exactly the loss function and ignoring cases where your training error is the average of the loss function and not just the loss function. Is that correct?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)#Introduction. It talks about the difference between the objective function that we minimize, the loss, and the regularization. When there's no regularization then the (average) loss and objective function can be the same

Comment: Nice link. After looking at the link, it's clear that 'the objective function that we minimize" === "loss + lamda*regularization_term".  Which means that when you remove the regularization term, then "the objective function that we minimize" === "loss", which contradicts "When there's no regularization then the (average) loss and objective function can be the same" . It contradicts the statement because we don't minimize the average in the 'objective function'. In fact, we take the gradient of the loss function itself (no average...and the regularization terms if there are any).

Comment: So it seems to me that it's more accurate to state that when there's no regularization then the loss and objective function can be the same (leaving out the word 'average').

Comment: there's no difference between minimizing the average loss and minimizing the total loss -- they just differ by a constant

Comment: Good point. That makes it seem really pointless to minimize the average loss when you put it like that :).. but on the other hand it seems like it would drastically reduce the rate at which your parameters can increase or decrease, given that you're adding gradient(loss/n) instead of gradient(loss) each iteration of the decent algorithm.